# Yii2 Multilingual. Can't reach the fields from the translation table

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, multilingual

I installed OmgDef/Multilingual via composer. Did everything step by step from the guide. The error that I get now is:

```
Getting unknown property: backend\models\PageAdminSearch::title
```

I added `joinWith('translation')` but nothing changes.This is my `PageAdmin` model and `PageAdminSearch`
PageAdmin:

```
<?php

namespace backend\models;

use omgdef\multilingual\MultilingualBehavior;
use omgdef\multilingual\MultilingualQuery;
use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "page_admin".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property int $id_in
 * @property int $enable
 * @property string $icon
 */
class PageAdmin extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function find()
    {
        return new MultilingualQuery(get_called_class());
    }

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $allLanguages = [];
        foreach (Yii::$app->params['languages'] as $title => $language) {
            $allLanguages[$title] = $language;
        }

        return [
            'ml' => [
                'class' => MultilingualBehavior::className(),
                'languages' => $allLanguages,
                //'languageField' => 'language',
                //'localizedPrefix' => '',
                //'requireTranslations' => false',
                //'dynamicLangClass' => true',
                //'langClassName' => PostLang::className(), // or namespace/for/a/class/PostLang
                'defaultLanguage' => Yii::$app->params['languageDefault'],
                'langForeignKey' => 'page_id',
                'tableName' => "{{%page_adminlang}}",
                'attributes' => [
                    'title',
                    'content',
                ]
            ],
        ];
    }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'page_admin';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['icon'], 'string'],
            [['id_in', 'enable'], 'integer']
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
            'id_in' => Yii::t('app', 'Id In'),
            'icon' => Yii::t('app', 'Icon'),
        ];
    }
}
```

PageAdminSearch:

```
<?php

namespace backend\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use backend\models\PageAdmin;

/**
 * PageAdminSearch represents the model behind the search form of `backend\models\PageAdmin`.
 */
class PageAdminSearch extends PageAdmin
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'id_in'], 'integer'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = PageAdmin::find()->joinWith('translations');

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'id_in' => $this->id_in,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'title', $this->title]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

`languageDefault` is `bg`. Did someone have the same problem? The explanation is not pretty big but I think the problem is clear enough :) Appreciate every advice!

Comment: added an answer see if it helps you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't used it tho but looking at your code you are adding a `joinWith` inside the `search()` function in the model, are you searching any field with name `title` inside the `translations` table using some gridview or search form

If that is so you need to declare a custom `attribute` inside your searchModel and add it to the safe `rules` and then use it because you are getting an error at the line

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'title', $this->title]);
```

so add a custom attribute on top of your `PageAdminSearch`

```
public $title
```

And it is always good to use an alias for the relation

```
 $query = PageAdmin::find()
 ->joinWith(['translations'=>function($q){
    $q->from('{{%transalations}} tr');
 }]);
```

then update your rules to the following

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id', 'id_in'], 'integer'],
        [['title'],'safe'],
    ];
}
```

and change the line to the following

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'tr.title', $this->title]);
```

Now run it won't show you the error.

Comment: In my certain case, no. But guess it can be helpful for someone else. Will upvote it :)

Comment: dude, you always do like this why didn't it helped in your case? when such thing happens do leave a comment on the answer so i could adjust it according to your requirements @TomaTomov